# Break up Review history links

Tags: feature-request, review

Under the user's profile page, All Actions->reviews, on a first visit it is not obvious that the link title and the review outcome link to separate pages.  They are very close together, with only a single space character separating them, and the only distinction is the bold styling and grey background.  I did not even notice the grey at first.

While a case could be made for "it's good enough", I think there is a case for making a positive improvement to break up these links.

**Currently:** The layout consists of a table with three columns.  The date, the action "reviewed", and the last column is stuffed with both the review outcome link(to the suggested edit) with the title link(to the actual question) which are separated by only a single space character.

**Dual Line option:** The convention used by other types of actions is to have the Question title link on the first line, and then one more line that summarizes the action in some way.  If we followed this convention, then the second line could have the outcome reason/summary, or if there are very long reasons it could be ellipsed as necesary.  I've mocked this up, with both the current top and proposed change below:

[image: proposed change]

**I think this is an improvement, more effectively separating the two links, and stylistically fits with other actions that appear in these lists.**

Even if this is not considered a good option, I'd like the site designers to consider finding some way to improve the separation of the two links.  **Maybe with a few more brains a better solution can be found.**  If it weren't for needing consistency with the "all" column, I would have suggested a four column layout instead of three.

(sorry if feature-request is the wrong tag, I couldn't find a better fit for suggested site design changes.)